# Как динамически изменять величину шага приращения в QDoubleSpinBoxDelegate?

Tags: c++, qt

В приложении C++ есть таблица QTableWidget, где некоторые колонки связаны с QDoubleSpinBoxDelegate, но величина шага приращения задаётся в той же строке другой колонки через QComboBoxDelegate. Спрашивается - как при редактировании ячейки в QDoubleSpinBoxDelegate задать значение шага.
Сам делегат:

```
#ifndef DOUBLESPINBOXDELEGATE_H
#define DOUBLESPINBOXDELEGATE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QItemDelegate>
#include <QDoubleSpinBox>

class DoubleSpinBoxDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
    double minVal;
    double maxVal;
    double oneStep;
    QString suffix;
public:
    DoubleSpinBoxDelegate(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    DoubleSpinBoxDelegate(QObject *parent, double min, double max, double step = 0.0001, QString suffix = "");

    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;

    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const;

    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setStepSize(double step);

};

#endif // DOUBLESPINBOXDELEGATE_H
```

Реализация:

```
#include "doublespinboxdelegate.h"

DoubleSpinBoxDelegate::DoubleSpinBoxDelegate(QObject *parent)
{
    minVal = 1.5;
    maxVal = 29.9999;
}

DoubleSpinBoxDelegate::DoubleSpinBoxDelegate(QObject *parent, double min, double max, double step, QString suffix)
{
    if (parent)
    {
        minVal = min;
        maxVal = max;
        oneStep = step;
        this->suffix = suffix;
    }
}

QWidget *DoubleSpinBoxDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{    
    QDoubleSpinBox *editor = new QDoubleSpinBox (parent);
    editor->setSuffix(tr(" MHz"));
    editor->setDecimals (6);
    editor->setMinimum(minVal);
    editor->setMaximum(maxVal);
    editor->setSingleStep(oneStep);

    return (QWidget *) editor;
}

void DoubleSpinBoxDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    double value = index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toDouble();

    QDoubleSpinBox *dSpinBox = static_cast<QDoubleSpinBox*>(editor);
    dSpinBox->setValue(value);
}

void DoubleSpinBoxDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QDoubleSpinBox *dSpinBox = static_cast<QDoubleSpinBox*>(editor);
    dSpinBox->interpretText();
    double value = dSpinBox->value();

    model->setData(index, value, Qt::EditRole);
}

void DoubleSpinBoxDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
}
```

Понятно, что в методе createEditor, надо задавать значение oneStep, но как его прочесть из другой колонки таблицы в этой же строке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас настройки редактора зависят от данных, то лучше их выполнять в `setEditorData`. Так по моему логичней. Как это сделать наиболее правильно зависит от проекта, ниже перечислю варианты:

```
void DoubleSpinBoxDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
   double value = index.data(Qt::EditRole).toDouble();

   QDoubleSpinBox *spin = dynamic_cast<QDoubleSpinBox*>(editor);
   spin->setValue(value);

   // можно обратиться прямо к модели, самый простой и быстрый вариант
   // но делегат будет работать только с одной моделью
   MyModel * model = dynamic_cast<MyModel*>(index.model());
   auto step1 = model->getMySpinBoxStep();

   // можно напрямую запросить нужную ячейку, чуть лучший вариант
   // так как делегат будет зависеть от структуры модели
   double step2 = index.model()->data(step_index, Qt::EditRole).toDouble();

   // можно задать для этого отдельную роль, это наиболее идеоматичный
   // способ так как типы делегата и модели связаны только через код роли
   double step3 = index.data(MyStepRole).toDouble();

   spin->setSingleStep(step2);
}
```

Напомню, что коды собственных ролей данных должны быть больше чем значение `Qt::UserRole`.

Comment: Спасибо, Вы кое-что прояснили, но возникают другие вопросы: как создать MyStepRole привязанную к нужной ячейке таблицы или как определить step_index, если в метод предан только &index текущей ячейки?

Comment: по варианту 2 у меня кое-что получилось:

        QModelIndex stepIndex = index.sibling(index.row(), SYNTESIS_STEP);
        double step2 = stepIndex.model()->data(stepIndex, Qt::EditRole).toDouble();

Но это вариант для одной таблицы, а у меня таблицы две, где информация в разных колонках. Так что желателен третий способ, который я пока не освоил.